# QT5.2 Resource files

Tags: c++, qt

Short yet annoying problem; I can't access anything defined within qt resource file (aka .qrc). I've followed the qt utorial for creating a widget application called TextFinder.According to it I've created all the necessary files and completed all the instructions yet I can't access the qrc contents.
 Inside the project folder I have files like:

```
TextFinder
  resources
   input.txt
  main.cpp
  textfinder.cpp
  textfinder.h
  TextFinder.pro
  TextFinder.pro.user
  TextFinder.qrc
  textfinder.ui
```

The contents of the qrc file is as follows:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/res">
        <file>resources/input.txt</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

To access the file within I opened the qrc in Editor right clicked on the file and chose copy resource path to clipboard option. This produced ":/res/resources/input.txt". So I just entered this to my function to open the file. This function looks like the following:

```
void TextFinder::loadTextFile()
{
    QFile inputFile(":/res/resources/input.txt");
    inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    if (inputFile.isOpen())
    {
        QTextStream txtStream(&inputFile);
        QString contents = txtStream.readAll();
        inputFile.close();

        ui->textEdit->setPlainText(contents);
        QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Resource file may be wrong?");
    }
}
```

When I run the application the runtime_error is thrown that tells me that it couldn't open the file. In the project file I have the qrc file defined as follows:

```
RESOURCES += \
    TextFinder.qrc
```

What is going wrong in here? Anyone could point out what i'm doing wrong?

Regards,
 Joe

Comment: I reproduced your steps and for me it all works, maybe you should just double-check all things (like user rights), possibly re-run qmake and stuff like that.

Comment: I've Double checked everything and i have written It correctly what i did. I'm using the following version (in Case there is an issue i'm nőt familiar with): qt-windows-opensource-5.2.0-msvc2010_opengl-x86-offline.exe

Comment: check inputFile.errorString(); Try with listing ":/" with QFileInfo.

Comment: @Joey try without first /. I'm not sure but Qt had some issue with resource paths starting from `/`. Try `:res/resources/input.txt` or even `:res/input.txt` - I'm not sure about subpaths. They may be cut if prefix is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Qt Resource System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/resources.html#compiled-in-resources) documentation:

> It is also possible to specify a path prefix for all files in the .qrc file using the qresource tag's prefix attribute:
>
> ```
> <qresource prefix="/myresources">
>     <file alias="cut-img.png">images/cut.png</file>
> </qresource>
> ```
>
> In this case, the file is accessible as :/myresources/cut-img.png.

So subpath is cut off when prefix is present